# Converting a structure from Little endian to Big endian

Tags: c, endianness

My problem is to convert a pointer to structure from little endian to big endian so that I can send it to network, since my structure is of 12 bytes or 92 bits I cannot apply any standard or non standard function given.

I am trying to Implement GTPv1U on my linux system, since my structure pointer is of 96 bits I tried to break it in three chunk of 32 bits each and then do conversion but I am unable to break it and I also doubt that this is not correct way to do it

Code of my structure

```
typedef struct  __attribute__((__packed__)) GTPv1Uheader{
    UInt8  version              :3;
    UInt8  ProtocolTypeFlag     :1;
    UInt8  Spare                :1;
    UInt8  ExtensionFlag        :1;
    UInt8  SequenceNumberFLAG   :1;
    UInt8  NpduNumberFlag       :1;
    UInt8  MessageType;
    UInt16 Length;
    UInt32 TEID;                    
    UInt16 SequenceNumber;
    UInt8  NPDUNumber;
    UInt8  NextExtensionheader;
} GTPv1UheaderT;
```

Assignment of values

```
GTPv1UheaderT * IntializeGTP(){
    GTPv1UheaderT *GTPv1UheaderP;
    GTPv1UheaderP = malloc(sizeof(GTPv1UheaderT));
    memset(GTPv1UheaderP, 0, (sizeof(GTPv1UheaderT)));
    GTPv1UheaderP->version              = 0x1;
    GTPv1UheaderP->ProtocolTypeFlag     = 0x1;
    GTPv1UheaderP->Spare                = 0x0;
    GTPv1UheaderP->ExtensionFlag        = 0x0;
    GTPv1UheaderP->SequenceNumberFLAG   = 0x1;
    GTPv1UheaderP->NpduNumberFlag       = 0x0;
    GTPv1UheaderP->MessageType          = 0x01;
    GTPv1UheaderP->Length               = 0x000C;
    GTPv1UheaderP->TEID                 = 0x00000001;
    GTPv1UheaderP->SequenceNumber       = 0x0000;
    GTPv1UheaderP->NPDUNumber           = 0x00;
    GTPv1UheaderP->NextExtensionheader  = 0x00;
    return GTPv1UheaderP;
}
```

Expected output: `32 01 00 0C 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00`

Actual output: `49 01 0C 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

EDIT: This was the swap function

```
long s; 
unsigned char k;
k=(unsigned char)GTPv1UheaderP;
s=(unsigned int)k;
s=ntohl(s);
printf("%ld\n",s);
```

I know that this wont work because my long is 32 bits where as pointer is of 96 bits. Any other solution

Comment: I see no code for the actual swapping. (and you dont need to swap the *pointer*, only the (de)serialised  elements/objects)

Comment: Re: your title: it's not a *pointer* that you want to convert. Sending pointers elsewhere is a bad idea. I'm also missing the part where you do your current conversion.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `htonu` or `htonl` function ("Host-to-Network byte order", u=u_short, l=u_long)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie htonu and htonl can work for only 64 bits not 96 bits

Comment: Byte-ordering is a property of individual scalars within your header, not of the whole header overall.  `htonl` and `htons` (not `htonu`) are the standard POSIX tools for converting from host to network byte order, and of course they are paired with `ntohl` and `ntohs` for the reverse transformations.  Or you can do it manually, of course, using an `unsigned char *` to write the individual bytes of each multibyte field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a whole `struct` from/to little or big endian does not make sense, because endianness is a property of a multi-byte scalar type representation, e.g. a single `UInt16` or `UInt32`. When converting a `struct` to its "on-the-wire representation" you go through it one element at a time, and prepare its representation element-by-element.

Bit fields represent a special case, because their ordering is implementation-defined. You need to serialize them into a single byte in the order that you prefer. Use `hton`/`ntoh` functions to do the conversion of the individual multi-byte elements, i.e. `Length` and `TEID`.

Comment: How can we serialise all those bit fields into single byte? I don't want to redefine structure as it can have side effect @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @KevalMalde [Here is a good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28740463/335858) on how this could be done.

Comment: While it is correct, that this is the only standard-conform and portable way to marshall structures, you should not conceal that it is common practice to convert the (byteorder-affected) structure members with hton(l/s), convert the structure pointer to a char pointer and put the information on the wire. This is not only done because the programmer is lazy, but is also _much_ faster in terms of (server) performance for example.